# When using PouchDB over HTTP as an API for CouchDB is data still stored in the browsers built-in database?

Tags: http, couchdb, pouchdb

When using PouchDB over HTTP as an API for CouchDB is data still stored in the browsers built-in database?

[PouchDB Docs](http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html#pouchdb_over_http)

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.

> PouchDB is not a self-contained database; it is a CouchDB-style abstraction layer over other databases.

In the case **... over HTTP** you specify a remote destination for data storage instead of a local store.

Comment: Thank you llabball. It looked to me like the database was in the browser, but I couldn't find an easy way to delete it and retest it.